I can´t add a Bar chart in my presentation powerpoint
I want add a Bar chart in my presentation powerpoint but have it this error: Argument 1 passed to PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Slide\AbstractSlide::addShape() must be an instance of PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\AbstractShape, instance of PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Chart\Type\Bar given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\produccion_tracking\app\Http\Controllers\ReporteConsultaController.php on line 760
I have tried many methods, how to implement $slide->addShape($chart), but I can't. This is the code that implements the 'addShape()' function:
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Chart;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Chart\Series;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Chart\Type\Line;
use PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Chart\Type\Bar;

 $templateProcessor = IOFactoryPPTX::load($url);
 $slide = $templateProcessor->getSlide(1);

 $data = [
            ['Enero', 100],
            ['Febrero', 200],
            ['Marzo', 150],
            ['Abril', 300],
          ];
          
          // Crear una instancia de la gráfica de barras
          $chart = new Bar();
          // Agregar las series de datos a la gráfica
          foreach ($data as $row) {
            $series = new Series($row[0], [$row[1]]);
            $chart->addSeries($series);
          }

          $chart->setBarGrouping(Bar::GROUPING_CLUSTERED);
          $slide->addShape($chart);


